# What does it mean? For What: "Well" in this sentence? Performing - noun or verb?

Tags: sentence, what

"Regularly performing well in worldwide livable city rankings, Vancouver has a new ambitious goal of becoming the greenest city in the world by 2020?"

Comment: It performs well (ranks highly) in the worldwide livable city rankings.

Comment: The performance was *good* --> it performed *well*.  I'm going from an adjective to an adverb.

Answer (score 1):

The word "well" in this sentence is an *adverb* - it modifies the verb "performing" and, as Jim notes, it means that Vancouver is highly ranked as being a very livable city. (Their performance in these rankings is very good.)